# Flutter provider: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class which triggers some functions from my provider:

```
...
Provider.of<MyRents>(context, listen: false).something();
...
```

The exception I get is:

```
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (24312): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
```

This is an initial check that needs to be done in a class and it modifies the provider updating it with some values for the tree later.
I understand the context can change and it can be unavailable, but how could I fix it? Calling my class method and separately, when it's done, calling the provider?

More info: this particular function is triggered by `getPastPurchases()` (in-app-purchases), called from `MyHomePage`'s `initState`

Comment: where in your code is this specific line. Context here is important... literally

Comment: Added info to question